# What is the best approach for classifying non-English text

Tags: machine-learning, classification, text

What would be the best approach for classifying non-English (Sinhala / Tamil) text? Currently I use [Fasttext](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText). Are there any better options?

I want to classify user questions into chatbot intents. Therefore, there may be many target classes.

Comment: Could you please describe your problem more? By many target classes you mean multi-class or multi-label as well?

Comment: Multi classes. There are more than 80 classes to predict. Need to classify a question into only one intent.

Comment: What's your data set balance?

Comment: Total of nearly 20, 000 sample questions belonging to 80 classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the best way would be to use pretrained embedder. Embedder encodes your text into language-agnostic latent space. You input your text and you get fixed-length numerical vector as an output. You can use latent space encodings as a feature vector, which you can use to train discriminative models. They also suit well for resampling like `SMOTE` or `ADASYN`.

Some time ago Facebook released a model called `LASER`. You can read about it [here](https://engineering.fb.com/ai-research/laser-multilingual-sentence-embeddings/). It supports Sinhala and Tamil as well. [Here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/LASER) is a github repository. There is also unofficial distribution on `pypi`. It substitutes internal tools for tokenization and BPE encoding. For sake of convenience I've been working mostly with this distribution and I can confirm it works just fine. [Here](https://github.com/yannvgn/laserembeddings) is a repository.

I'd also suggest to consider embedder abuse. It covers a lot of languages, which means you can train your models on e.g. English and prediction will work for Tamil out of the box!

Natural language is hyper-dimensional space and most seminal models are using encoders. To my knowledge it is the go-to approach for any language.